# How can I delete a <dict> object in a Django QuerySet

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have this queryset in Django (lets call it qs) with 3 different object instances. Two of them are identical except for the image file:

```
    <QuerySet [
    
    {'investment__name': 'Stefano', 'investment__net_returns': Decimal('11.00'), 
    'investment__my_images__image': '**investments/None/IMG01.JPG**'}
    
    {'investment__name': 'Stefano','investment__net_returns': Decimal('11.00'),
    'investment__my_images__image': '**investments/None/IMG02.JPG**'},
    
    {'investment__name': 'Alberto','investment__net_returns': Decimal('22.00'),
    'investment__my_images__image': '**investments/None/IMG03.JPG**'}
    
    ]>
```

I want to render in a template only the first object and the third of the queryset. I'm trying to delete the second but i don't know how to delete a queryset Object.

The way I tried is something like this:

```
    inv=""
    for i,investment_instance in enumerate(qs):
        if investment_instance['investment__name']==inv:
            investment_instance.delete()
        else:
            inv=investment_instance['investment__name']
            im=investment_instance['investment__my_images__image']
```

But of course investment_instance.delete() doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What query was used to create your *qs* ?

Comment: Someobject.objects.values('field1', 'field2').annotate(Sum('field2'))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the QuerySet in 'temp_query' variable

temp_query = list(temp_query)

del temp_query[1] // deleting 2nd element from the list.

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine! I wonder if this is the only way (queryset transformed in a list), or there's a more "Django-way" to do that...but again, thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: I have never faced this kind of situation but you can also use .exclude() functionality in your filter. That will exclude the unnecessary object.